# Use Date from most recent and delete others SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to delete all other rows but keep one which has oldest date in it ?

E.g.

```
 Person

 ID         Name         Birthdate

1            A            20160101
2            B            20160202
3            C            20160303
```

Is there any query that returns me ID  of person row with OLDEST birthdate and DELETE all other rows that is

```
 returns 3 and deletes all other rows
```

If all birthdays are SAME date then return me row with LOWEST ID

Thanks

Aiden

Comment: One query cannot both *return* data and *delete rows*.  What do you really want to do?

Comment: May be a cursor ?

Comment: Can a cursor do this ? For all the records, it does the above rules ?

Comment: Do you really mean delete from table or do you simply mean return the Most recent date and no others?

Comment: Need better sample data and desired results.  Your question is not very clear

Comment: Delete but I got the answer, we can do it with using temporary tables :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, if by DELETE you mean to remove records from the database and by RETURN you mean selecting a row, AND if you can use a batch of two queries, you could do:

```
DELETE Person
WHERE ID <> (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID
    FROM Person
    ORDER BY Birthdate DESC, ID
);

SELECT TOP 1 ID
FROM Person;
```

Ordering the subquery last for Id ASC garantees that, if there are equal Birthdates, only the lowest ID is returned.
The SELECT in the end will return the only remaining Person.

If you require just one query for both operations, then I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you use ROW_NUMBER it will help you identify the records you want more correctly due to the fact that Birthdate could have ties.  So build a Common Table Expression [CTE] that will identify the row you are looking for.  Then if you actually want to delete the records from the database delete from the cte, but if you only want to return and not modify the data (more likely) just select where the row number is 1.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (ID INT, Name CHAR(1), Birthdate DATE)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES
(1,'A','2016/01/01')
,(2,'B','2016/02/02')
,(3,'C','2016/03/03')
,(4,'D','2016/01/01') --note this is a tie for oldest birthdate

;WITH cte AS (
SELECT
    *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Birthdate, Id) as RowNumber
FROM
    @Table
)
```

So if you really want to modify/delte the data you would do the following right after the above code:

```
DELETE FROM cte WHERE RowNumber > 1

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

If you really just want the 1 row matching your criteria you would simply put this statement after the above CTE.

```
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE RowNumber = 1
```